# How to run mysql commands through shell script?

Tags: mysql, scripts

```
mysql -u root -pmysql;

SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
```

I want to create a shell script which will execute these command and return the result.

How may i run this commands through shell script ?

Comment: You have posted essentially this same question in a couple of forms in at least a few different Stack Exchange sites. Please do not do any more cross posting or minor-variant posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -pmysql << eof
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
eof
```

Comment: As described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005057/how-to-provide-a-password-while-executing-mysqldump-through-shell-script/1378053#1378053 providing password on command line is a security issue. This is even worse when it comes to exposing the password for database user `root` as given in this example. Never ever do that! User `root` is available to any other user on your system. Even user `www-data` or `nobody` can connect to the MySQL as `root` and drop all your databases in a second.