# How to provide a password while executing `mysqldump` through shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, mysql

I wrote a batch file which establishing the connection to linux server which I am able to do so, after this I am trying to take the mysqldump to some certain directory, it has all 777 permissions but linux system ask me to "Enter Password" which is nothing but empty, and manually I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I just need to execute my script which just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so that execution will happen automatically. Below are some details.

batch file:

```
plink.exe -ssh user@host -m command.txt
```

`command.txt`:

```
mysqldump -uve -p -R -E --single-transaction --databases mydb|gzip > /home/user/mydb_bkup.gz
```

This is the image which is prompting me to enter password:
[image: this is the image which is prompting me to enter password]

Please provide me some inputs so that I can enter the password and execute my command automatically.

Comment: If you haven't set any password for the used account, omitting `-p` as command line argument should suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand you, it's the **command** you're running that asks for password. Your line is:

```
mysqldump -uve -p -R -E --single-transaction --databases mydb|gzip > /home/user/mydb_bkup.gz
```

If we head over to `man mysql`, we read the following:

> The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one.

You have not specified anything - because the shell threats space as an argument separator. Either set a password for the mysql user, remove `-p` from the command.txt file, or... modify your command to the following:

```
mysqldump -uve --password="" -R -E --single-transaction --databases mydb|gzip > /home/user/mydb_bkup.gz
```

Here we explicitly specify a blank password.

Comment: This syntax `mysqldump -u'user-name' -p'the-password' ...` is also applicable.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that `-p''` would work. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: You can also just write the password straight after `-p` so something like this `-pY0ur_PaSSW0Rd_9o3s_H3R3`

Answer (score 1):

Providing password on command line or in environment variable should be considered risky. While mysqldump is running, tools such as ps will expose command line arguments, filesystems like procfs will expose environment variables. This doesn't change with read-only accounts used for backups for they can still leak information worth protecting.

Using an extra defaults file containing username and password is considered the preferrable way.

https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/database-servers/how-to-create-a-credential-file-for-mysql/